# Using SVGs in lieu of html/css

Tags: css, svg, seo, html

I've been mocking up a landing page in Adobe Illustrator, and I'm about to begin coding it.

Is there a reason I shouldn't just export the whole page as an SVG and use that in lieu of recreating everything in html/css?

The only cons I can think of are:

1. SEO, as I won't have regular text 
   (*easy enough to just remove text from SVGs and recreate in  html*)
2. User interaction (buttons etc) 
   (*same solution as the SEO problem*)
3. Responsiveness with respect to elements repositioning at different viewport sizes. 
   (*trickier; but already mocked up a few different layouts for different device sizes, so i can just serve different versions*)

My suspicion is there's something I'm missing, because I haven't been able to find anything online addressing this approach.

Some clarification:

- I believe SVG compatibility gets dodgy before IE9 or so, but my product involves a chrome extension, so this isn't a huge concern
- my design is Material Design-inspired, so there are a lot of colored divs & the like. this is a good approximation ([source](http://www.materialup.com/posts/find-your-next-home)):

  [image]

While the buttons and text would best be handled with HTML/CSS/JS, I'm interested in the reasons that the rest of it (i.e., the image and layout components) can't be handled w/ a single SVG.

Comment: Because that is something you go to hell for. 8SVG stands for Scalable Vector Graphics; `image/svg+xml`8. It would be like using png as your site. And to be more serious - add compatibility, render time and caching/loading to your list.

Comment: what if my idea of eternal damnation is having to make everything IE8 compatible? :)  i think svg would be better than PNG precisely for file size considerations (thanks to compression, etc.), but you're right, it's definitely something I'll have to keep an eye on. in my case, for now, i'm assuming file sizes will be manageable w/ either option

Comment: Regarding your edit: Using SVG as images or site components. Wait. Why are you even asking? That's why it was brought to us with HTML5 (let's pretend it wasn't possible earlier).

Comment: my question isn't whether or not i can use svgs as images/site components, it's what are the shortfalls of using a *single* SVG.  this as opposed to, say, using html/css to do the site layout, sections, etc. and using separate SVGs for images--i.e., just like you would use PNGs or GIFs.

Comment: How do you want to nest `html` in `svg`? With foreignObejct? The thing is that svg is simply not meant to be used as a website.

Comment: yeah that was one of the hurdles I figured. tentative plan was to just make the SVG background and position elements over it as appropriate. definitely not a cut/paste solution, but when i weigh it against fiddling with html/css just to recreate what i've already made in illustrator, it starts to seem comparatively simple.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -1):

How can you add a footer in SVG always at the bottom of the page with dynamic page content?

I think that the main difference is that a SVG is a canvas with fixed height and width, html document has a dynamic-sized window.

Comment: SVGs does not necessarily need to have a fixed width and height. They are completely responsive (proportionally scaled) to their parent's dimensions if no dimensions on the SVG itself is defined.

Comment: Elements may use percentual size relative to the svg box, but inside everything has absolute position, nothing like liquid layout.